# PHP - Using cURL to access HTTPS (SSL) protected sites

Tags: php, ssl, curl, https

The following code returns Exit code 58.

From cURL documentation:
CURLE_SSL_CERTPROBLEM (58) 
problem with the local client certificate.

```
// create a new CURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, getcwd() . $CERT);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD,"XXXXX");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content Type: text/xml',
    'User-Agent: XXXXX',
    'User-Name: XXXXX'
));

$RESPONSE = curl_exec($ch);  

var_dump($RESPONSE);

// close CURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure the file in `getcwd() . $CERT` exists and is a valid PEM certificate. If it seems ok, set the following option to get more SSL certification details output to STDERR:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, true);
```

Note that this setting only has effect if `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` is set to true, which you already have.

Comment: Thanks Kaivosukeltaja! It was actually a silly problem with the certificate path on the server!

Comment: No problem, Ren! If either of the answers proved useful, don't forget to upvote and/or mark them as accepted. :)

Answer (score 0):

> problem with the local client certificate

hmm a bit vague. Seems to mean Curl doen't like the certificate, rather than the remote system doesn't like it. Is it in PEM format? Public and private keys in certificate? Readable by webserver uid?

Comment: Yeah I agree I wish it could be more specific. It is in PEM format. Also, there are no issues accessing it through the CLI (curl -v -k --cert xxx.pem --pass xxx https://xxx) so it shouldn't be a problem with the certificates? It seems to be a problem with how I'm using it in PHP.